# Summarize by timestamp and id to new columns in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

My data looks like this:

```
TagId   Timestamp                 Value
23  2022-06-19T10:25:51.7229267Z    90
22  2022-06-19T10:25:51.7229267Z    90
21  2022-06-19T10:25:51.7229267Z    90
21  2022-06-19T10:30:51.7229267Z    90
22  2022-06-19T10:30:51.7229267Z    90
```

I want to aggregate it by hour, so I query like this:

```
T
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where TagId in (21, 22, 23)
| summarize round(avg(todouble(Value)), 2) by bin(Timestamp, 1h), TagId
| order by Timestamp asc
```

The returned data looks like this:

```
Timestamp          TagId   avg_Value
2022-06-20T12:00:00Z    21  59
2022-06-20T12:00:00Z    23  59
2022-06-20T12:00:00Z    22  59
2022-06-20T13:00:00Z    23  58.08
2022-06-20T13:00:00Z    22  58.08
2022-06-20T13:00:00Z    21  58.17
```

Is it possible to combine "same" timestamps and instead create new columns for each TagId, so the returned data would be instead something like this:

```
Timestamp            21_avg_Value 22_avg_Value 23_avg_Value
2022-06-20T12:00:00Z    59            59           59
2022-06-20T13:00:00Z    59            59           59
2022-06-20T14:00:00Z    59            59           59
2022-06-20T15:00:00Z    58.08         58.08        58.08
2022-06-20T16:00:00Z    58.08         58.08        58.08
2022-06-20T17:00:00Z    58.17         58.17        58.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
let T = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend Timestamp = ago(5h*rand()), TagId = 20 + toint(rand(5)), Value = rand(100));  
T
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where TagId in (21, 22, 23)
| summarize round(avg(todouble(Value)), 2) by bin(Timestamp, 1h), TagId
| evaluate pivot(TagId, take_any(avg_Value), Timestamp)
| order by Timestamp asc
```

| Timestamp | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-20T08:00:00Z | 49.93 | 49.05 | 49.67 |
| 2022-07-20T09:00:00Z | 49.42 | 49.71 | 49.53 |
| 2022-07-20T10:00:00Z | 49.4 | 49.41 | 49.39 |
| 2022-07-20T11:00:00Z | 49.53 | 49.53 | 49.4 |
| 2022-07-20T12:00:00Z | 49.68 | 49.41 | 49.56 |
| 2022-07-20T13:00:00Z | 49.84 | 49.81 | 49.63 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02QwU7DMBBE75X6D3O0wYckVU%20I3rlHXKsNXhKL2I4cJ1DUj2djBK0lX2bWb2Y9ckaLZ3jKnByN7ptVotAzHN5T9KiRI%20qqHMyZJ1Gu4K/MwaJ1nudMfhIC9VEdhwd5bJXWBi31L1b0psKjMFzIqnjHzXylcWExiyJ0rZ%20A/a7d7674HDjxHfpU0IfK6ju3wF2AamqDppF7KPa8eE9JtkCKi7Bp7VWONi7dyKqkbvGNRndB54L6jzGoh7/WG4hXGZZPweTWmFXRDTJ98JnCZeOef3HmVrU0iMly2vC3DWh%20%20wGDdP54aAEAAA==)

In principle there is no need for `summarize` before `pivot`, however `pivot` does not accept `round` around the aggregation function, yielding the following error:

> evaluate pivot(): the following error(s) occurred while evaluating the
> output schema: evaluate pivot(): aggregation function 'round' is not
> supported. Supported functions are
> (count,sum,dcount,avg,variance,stdev,max,min,any,take_any,make_bag,make_list,make_set)

```
let T = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend Timestamp = ago(5h*rand()), TagId = 20 + toint(rand(5)), Value = rand(100));  
T
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where TagId in (21, 22, 23)
| extend Timestamp = bin(Timestamp, 1h)
| evaluate pivot(TagId, avg(todouble(Value)), Timestamp)
| order by Timestamp asc
```

| Timestamp | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-20T08:00:00Z | 49.639317570437491 | 49.688689968741123 | 49.418424208224586 |
| 2022-07-20T09:00:00Z | 49.49681320887283 | 49.509350879412878 | 49.443463251113222 |
| 2022-07-20T10:00:00Z | 49.64722369517461 | 49.51051396034164 | 49.373391203994082 |
| 2022-07-20T11:00:00Z | 49.175818954738688 | 49.452813225782286 | 49.633952188451367 |
| 2022-07-20T12:00:00Z | 49.575321744736776 | 49.568760191728025 | 49.4777564329407 |
| 2022-07-20T13:00:00Z | 49.372085830272567 | 49.69027496271368 | 49.533668459200371 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PvU7EMBCE%205PuHaZcQ4okp6sQ19NH9A5eEkuJHTl74Uf38CyLQCmw5MIznm9nJxZ0eMTshUv0U/xkKj4NjIjXkmc0kIymtoNVeFHlBn4XTgFdnHkVPy9K8EOm83in4UDOVej88BRUb2vcKyMmIfPO3%20azn66spilKd%204BOB664%20GGt5EL79AXQ5/q4HauwWMCtU2FttV7MvufYn1M9Peu0Iw/HzetoEtjiVsWMmAFvw0kOeRrPzFZSVvlN23JXAIX9B%207IX59%20QJfOiLPSQEAAA==)